# Regular expression to find the closest matches of text between tags

Tags: .net, regex

I need to detect text between tags in .NET code, something like that:

```
ololo <z>text needed to be found</z> azaza
```

But string can contain multiple tags entries:

```
asd <z>text1</z> dgfh <z>text2</z> gfhj
```

Simple regular expression (`<z>.+</z>`) cannot recognize multiple entries and parses match from first till last symbols.
I've tried to build expression to look for any symbol between tags but not inculde closing tag (`<z>.+[^(<z>)]<\/z>`), but it does't works because of `[ ]` expression logic.

What expression will be correct?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex might appear easy at the beginning, but then problems might multiply. Why not use an HTML parser to do it right from the beginning? To parse XML, you can use an XML parser.

Comment: Input is not habitual HTML. unfortunately. Also, text, parsed from input string, will be shown in control that cannot recognize HTML tags. So, I have to build custom parser :(

Comment: Please add details to the question. Are these MIF tags or something like that? How are you going to tell them from, say `<email@gmail.com>`? Otherwise, judging from the details in your question, I still can advise `XElement.Parse`.

Comment: You can handle your certain example with non-greedy mode (just google it). But in general case with nested tags it is **impossible** to do it with regex.

Comment: You string will need to have some kind of defined format, either XML or other. Otherwise there will be problems sooner or later. (E.g. what if the text was to contain the tag?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = "asd <z>text1</z> dgfh <z>text2</z> gfhj";
string pattern = "<z.*?>(.*?)</z>";         
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);

foreach (Match match in r.Matches(text))
{           
    string textBetweenTags = match.Groups[1].ToString();
    //your logic here
}
```

Comment: that's helped, great thanks

Comment: and thanks for all in this thread)

Comment: `<z>(.*?)</z>` will suffice unless your tag contains attributes.

Comment: This [will break at `<z att=">">Something here</z>`](https://regex101.com/r/rG3iU8/2). `>` usually does not have to be serialized.